# WinForm not receiving messages except right after creation

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, winapi

I've got some unmanaged code sitting in a DLL.  It publishes some methods that my calling (managed) code uses to hook into some COM notifications.  Rather than deal with unmanaged code calling back into managed code, I've created a hidden Control derived object and am passing its handle property which the unmanaged code then uses as a parameter to SendMessage.

My Control derived class:

```
class InteropWindow : Control
{
  //delegate 
  private Handler m_callback;
  //window message
  private uint m_message;

  public InteropWindow(Handler callback, uint message)
    : base() 
  {
    m_callback = callback;
    m_message = message;
  }

  protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
  {
    if (m.Msg == m_message)
    {
      m_callback(new IntPtr((int)m.WParam));
    }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
  }
}
```

Relevant line in unmanaged code:

```
SendMessage(m_notify, m_window_message, (WPARAM)pData, 0);
```

m_window_message & m_message are the same (both from RegisterWindowMessage), and m_notify == InteropWindow.Handle (pData varies, but is used as an opaque handle in the managed code).  The unmanaged code is being invoked.  These facts have been confirmed via debugging.

Shortly after I create the InteropWindow, the calls to SendMessage succeed.  Afterwards (seconds later) the messages stop getting to WndProc, though there is no indication of any error.

The question is, what am I doing wrong here?

---

I've ruled out lifecycle issues (to the best of knowledge anyway), and played with HandleRef to no avail.

---

Edit the second.

I've re-written this to use function calls instead, which while fraught with its own perils, works a bit more like I'd expect.  I've come to suspect this is a COM threading issue, but that's just a gut feeling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you try passing your managed window's handle as a HandleRef?  C# can marshal a HandleRef as an IntPtr and vice versa, I've seen Microsoft use that trick quite a bit when decompiling some of their stuff.

You can also load up a .Net profiler and watch the GC.  It would be nice to know if your app is breaking right after a collect.

Comment: I've confirmed the handle stays valid through GCs; or, at the very least, there's absolutely no indication that it becomes invalid ever.  No invocation of Control.HandleDestroyed, no invalid handle warnings on use, no first chance exceptions anywhere, no nothing.

Comment: Could you instead try making an event on your COM object?  I've been the subscriber on the managed side and it might be a much simpler solution.  I am not sure how make the event on the COM/unmanaged side, however.